# Java sockets - How to send a message from client c1 to server s, and then from s to client c2

Tags: java, sockets, server, notifications, client

i have this situation :

2 clients : c1,c2

1 server : s

I need to send a message m from c1 to s, and then i need that s sends a notification message to c2.
I'm using Java Sockets.
The code i have is quite simple to send a message from c1 to s :

> Server

```
try {
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);
    System.out.println("Server ready to accept connections");
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = listener.accept();
            try {
                BufferedReader in =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                Scanner x = new Scanner(in);
                System.out.println("Client has sent :");
                while (x.hasNextLine()){
                    System.out.println(x.nextLine());
                }
                PrintWriter out =
                        new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                out.println("OK");
                out.flush();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
                finally
            {
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
```

> Client

```
Socket s = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket("localhost", 9090);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    try {
        PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
        out.println("Random Text");
        out.flush();
        s.shutdownOutput();
        //out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    Scanner y = new Scanner(input);
    String answer = "";
    while (y.hasNextLine()) {
        answer = answer.concat(y.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println("Answer :");
    System.out.println(answer);
    System.out.println(answer);
```

Now, how can i edit my code to do what i said ?
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to communicate between clients you have to use threads to do so. So how it will work will be you have to capture both clients and put them in the same thread.

```
public static void startServer() {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9090);
    executorService.execute(() -> {
       Socket client1 = server.accept();
       Socket client2 = server.accept();
       executorService.execute(new ServerConnection(client1, client2));
    });
}
```

The ServerConnection class will take two clients (Socket) which you can use to communicate between client to server to client. Think of the ServerConnection as data coming from the clients and the server will react accordingly.